# Google sheets regex expression

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Anyone can help me with this regular expression? I need to extract the price from a list of items.

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>22,21<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&euro;</span></bdi></span>.
```

I found this, but I am not extracting the ",".

```
=REGEXREPLACE(H8;"\D+"; "")*1
```

Comment: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>22,21<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&euro;</span></bdi></span>

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit the post to include that information.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\d+,\d+")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sql
=REGEXEXTRACT(H8;"(\d[\d,]*)<span\s+class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&euro;")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OEkECt/2).

**Details**

- `(\d[\d,]*)` - Capturing group 1 (the group value is the return value of the `REGEXEXTRACT` function): a digit and then any zero or more digits or commas
- `<span\s+class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&euro;` - a literal string with any one or more whitespaces between the tag name and the class attribute.